# Magento Grid Component not Sorting Correctly

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent

I've configured a grid component in Magento -- and the sorting behavior seems broken.  Where can I debug this on the javascript level, and/or does anyone else have any idea why this might be happening?

If I sort the grid once, an ajax request is made, and everything sorts correctly.

[image]

**However, the second sort, without an ajax request, renders the grid with all the same IDs.**

[image]

The behavior is **not** repeated on Magento core grids, so I'm pretty sure this is something I'm doing. I just don't know the ui component system well enough to know where to start debugging this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alright, I can't pretend to understand why yet, but the problem was the `data` argument of my `dataProvider` argument.

```
<!-- ... -->
<argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
    <!-- ... --->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- ... -->
</argument>
<!-- ... -->
```

When I compared this to a few of the core grids, the `data` argument was missing a `storageConfig` node, with an `indexField` sub-node with the primary key of my model.

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">pulsestorm_commercebug_log_id</item>
        </item>                    

    </item>                          
</argument>
```

When I added these nodes, sorting functionality was restored.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem, I imagine it is falling back or loading values from storage by the row index rather than data row id, although it makes no sense why the data is duplicated.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thanks @alan , This worked for me.

Comment: Thank @alan worked for me too.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**

This is an interesting problem indeed.

Here's how I understood the system but I may not be 100% right.

As you have seen clicking the header column generates an AJAX request to the following route: `/admin_key/mui/index/render` with the following parameters:

- filters[placeholder]
- isAjax
- namespace
- paging[current]
- paging[pageSize]
- search
- sorting[direction]
- sorting[field]

The last one is the field on which you're sorting your grid.

This route is declared by default in `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml`:

```
<insertListing class="Magento\Ui\Component\Container">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/insert-listing</item>
            <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            <item name="render_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="dataLinks" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="imports" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="exports" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="realTimeLink" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</insertListing>
```

But in a listing ui_component XML it is also declared:

```
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">page_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
```

This route is handled by `app/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php` based on the namespace parameter (which is normally the name of your UI Component)

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->_request->getParam('namespace') === null) {
        $this->_redirect('admin/noroute');
        return;
    }

    $component = $this->factory->create($this->_request->getParam('namespace'));
    $this->prepareComponent($component);
    $this->_response->appendBody((string) $component->render());
}
```

Where the `prepareComponent` method is recursive on the child components:

```
protected function prepareComponent(UiComponentInterface $component)
{
    foreach ($component->getChildComponents() as $child) {
        $this->prepareComponent($child);
    }
    $component->prepare();
}
```

When the column component is prepared, the column sorting is handled by `app/code/Magento/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php`:

```
public function prepare()
{
    $this->addFieldToSelect();

    $dataType = $this->getData('config/dataType');
    if ($dataType) {
        $this->wrappedComponent = $this->uiComponentFactory->create(
            $this->getName(),
            $dataType,
            array_merge(['context' => $this->getContext()], (array) $this->getData())
        );
        $this->wrappedComponent->prepare();
        $wrappedComponentConfig = $this->getJsConfig($this->wrappedComponent);
        // Merge JS configuration with wrapped component configuration
        $jsConfig = array_replace_recursive($wrappedComponentConfig, $this->getJsConfig($this));
        $this->setData('js_config', $jsConfig);

        $this->setData(
            'config',
            array_replace_recursive(
                (array)$this->wrappedComponent->getData('config'),
                (array)$this->getData('config')
            )
        );
    }

    $this->applySorting();

    parent::prepare();
}
```

Where the `applySorting()` method is based on the sorting parameter and it simply adds the order to the data provider:

```
protected function applySorting()
{
    $sorting = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('sorting');
    $isSortable = $this->getData('config/sortable');
    if ($isSortable !== false
        && !empty($sorting['field'])
        && !empty($sorting['direction'])
        && $sorting['field'] === $this->getName()
    ) {
        $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addOrder(
            $this->getName(),
            strtoupper($sorting['direction'])
        );
    }
}
```

Once every component is prepared, the action class renders the component (again recursively) for the response:

```
$this->_response->appendBody((string) $component->render());
```

I reckon those are the important PHP steps of what happens during the sorting.

Now to the JS, the render and update URLs (declared in `definition.xml` above) are assigned to the element in `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/insert.js`:

```
return Element.extend({
    defaults: {
        content: '',
        template: 'ui/form/insert',
        showSpinner: true,
        loading: false,
        autoRender: true,
        visible: true,
        contentSelector: '${$.name}',
        externalData: [],
        params: {
            namespace: '${ $.ns }'
        },
        renderSettings: {
            url: '${ $.render_url }',
            dataType: 'html'
        },
        updateSettings: {
            url: '${ $.update_url }',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        imports: {},
        exports: {},
        listens: {},
        links: {
            value: '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataScope}'
        },
        modules: {
            externalSource: '${ $.externalProvider }'
        }
    }
```

Still in this file, there's a `requestData` method that is used to retrieve the AJAX data:

```
    requestData: function (params, ajaxSettings) {
        var query = utils.copy(params);

        ajaxSettings = _.extend({
            url: this['update_url'],
            method: 'GET',
            data: query,
            dataType: 'json'
        }, ajaxSettings);

        this.loading(true);

        return $.ajax(ajaxSettings);
    }
```

You can see that this method is called when the `render()` method is called:

```
        $.async({
            component: this.name,
            ctx: '.' + this.contentSelector
        }, function (el) {
            self.contentEl = $(el);
            self.startRender = true;
            params = _.extend({}, self.params, params || {});
            request = self.requestData(params, self.renderSettings);
            request
                .done(self.onRender)
                .fail(self.onError);
        });
```

Once this is done, a callback method is called to apply the data.
It is `onRender()` :

```
    onRender: function (data) {
        this.loading(false);
        this.set('content', data);
        this.isRendered = true;
        this.startRender = false;
    }
```

I reckon that's where the new content is being applied.

Comment: Code Columbo...